# Webpack with Bugsnag

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, bugsnag

I'm using bugsnag to send exceptions for future debugging of my web app.

When I use webpack with source-maps, the stack trace is showing the line of the main bundle and not the specific source file.

Any idea how to see the error on the specific file?

Comment: Hello, I work at Bugsnag. There are several reasons the source maps might not work. They might be invalid or they may have failed to download. You should contact bugsnag directly using the '?' Intercom support icon on the error page in question so we can more easily see what may be going on. Is the javascript file in question online somewhere so it can be examined?